# Телеграмм бот реагирующий на цифры

Tags: python, telebot

Имеется данная часть кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['append'])
def nickname(message):
 global us_id, res, a, G, res2
 msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите число приглашений(ТОЛЬКО ЦИФРЫ)')
 us_id = message.from_user.id  
   cursor.execute('SELECT user_invite FROM user_inv WHERE user_id=' + str(us_id))
 a = cursor.fetchone()                 cursor.execute('SELECT A1 FROM user_inv     WHERE user_id=' + str(us_id))
 G=cursor.fetchone()
 res = functools.reduce(lambda sub, ele: sub * 10 + ele, a)
 res2 = functools.reduce(lambda sub, ele: sub * 10 + ele, G)
 bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, nickname_2)
 @bot.message_handler(commands=['new'])
def new(message):
 global us_id, res, a
 us_id = message.from_user.id
 N=0
 us_invite=0
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Админ id = ' + str(us_id) + ' Занесен в базу данных, успешно ')
 db_table_val_2(user_id=us_id, user_invite=us_invite, Norm=N) 
def db_table_val():
 cursor.execute('UPDATE user_inv SET user_invite=' + str(us_invite) + ', A1=' +str(N) + ' where user_id=' + str(us_id))
 conn.commit()

def nickname_2(message):
 global us_invite, N 
   try: 
     N= int(res2) + int(message.text)
     us_invite = int(res) + int(message.text)
 bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Админ id = ' + str(us_id) + ' Всего пригласил ' + str(us_invite) + '\n' + 'Еженедельная норма = ' + str(N) +'/30')
 db_table_val()
 except ValueError:
 msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите пожалуйста ЧИСЛО')
 bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, nickname_2)

    def db_table_val_2(user_id: int, user_invite: int, Norm:int):
     cursor.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO user_inv (user_id, user_invite, A1) VALUES(?, ?, ?)', (user_id, user_invite, Norm) )
     conn.commit()
```

Хочу убрать команды со / и сделать чтобы бот постоянно ждал и когда кто-то в группе вводил число(любое) то бот срабатывал искал человека в БД использовал данные из Базы и обновляет данные в базе (по типу как в моем коде), если человека нету в базе то бот создавал новые столбцы и вел учет. Подскажите как переработать бота, чтобы он после записи в бд возвращался в ожидание нового числа.

P.s. извиняюсь за слетевшую табуляцию, с телефона не удобно было копипастить код. Прикрепляю скриншот данного участка кода, для подроьности

[image: код с табуляцией, не все строуи влезли в экран, но табуляции видны]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать что-то наподобие:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def func(message):
    if message.text.isdigit():#если сообщение состоит только из цифр`
```

Comment: Спасибо, я уже сделал через проверку типа текста сообщения на int если оно int то реагировать, если нет то pass